# Horizontal recyclerview disappeares if I visit other tabs

Tags: java, android, xml

In my android project, there are three tabs in the main page. I placed the horizontal recyclerview in the third tab. it works fine for the first time, but when I visit first tab and come back, the horizontal recyclerview gets disappeared. Someone please help me 
codes are given below.

Tab3.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Suggestions" />

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/fragmentContainer"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="180dp"

            />

    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:scrollbars="vertical" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

recycler_items.xml

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/card_view"
    android:layout_width="120dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="5dp"
    card_view:cardCornerRadius="4dp">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/card_height"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:weightSum="4"
        >
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dip"
            android:layout_weight="3.2"
            android:orientation="vertical">
            <FrameLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal">
                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/coverImageView"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:scaleType="centerCrop"/>
                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="left|bottom"
                    android:background="@android:drawable/screen_background_dark_transparent"
                    android:orientation="vertical">
                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/titleTextView"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:padding="16dp"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/text_size"
                        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                        android:textStyle="bold"/>
                </LinearLayout>
            </FrameLayout>
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dip"
            android:layout_weight="0.8"
            android:gravity="center|right"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/likeImageView"
                android:layout_width="@dimen/icon_width"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/icon_height"
                android:padding="@dimen/icon_padding"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_like" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/shareImageView"
                android:layout_width="@dimen/icon_width"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/icon_height"
                android:padding="@dimen/icon_padding"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_share" />
        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

fragment_horizontal_list_view.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_left_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_right_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/cardView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Tab3.java

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.DefaultItemAnimator;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

/**
 * Created by Arshad on 09-06-2017.
 */

public class Tab3 extends Fragment {
    ListView listView;
    listItemAdapterPop listItemAdapter_Pop;
    String[] names = {"Hrithik","Ranbir","AkshayKumar","Amir Khan","Shahidi Kapoor"};
    String[] type = {"Bollywood actor","Mollywood Actor","Dancer","Playback Singer","DJ"};
    int[] images = {R.drawable.index1,R.drawable.index2,R.drawable.index3,R.drawable.index4,R.drawable.index5};
    private List<Artists> artistList = new ArrayList<>();
    private RecyclerView recyclerView;
    private ArtistAdapter mAdapter;

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab3,container,false);
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
//        listView = (ListView)view.findViewById(R.id.listView_pop);
//        listItemAdapter_Pop = new listItemAdapterPop(getActivity(),names,images,type);
//        listView.setAdapter(listItemAdapter_Pop);

        //listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
          //  @Override
            //public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
          //      Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "you can view the profile of :"+names[i], Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        //    }
        //});

        FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
        Fragment fragment = fm.findFragmentById(R.id.fragmentContainer);

        if (fragment == null) {
            fragment = new HorizontalListViewFragment();
            ;
            fm.beginTransaction()
                    .add(R.id.fragmentContainer, fragment)
                    .commit();
        }


        recyclerView = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);


        mAdapter = new ArtistAdapter(artistList);
        RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
        recyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
        recyclerView.addItemDecoration(new DividerItemDecoration(getActivity(), LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL));
// set the adapter
        recyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);

        prepareArtistData();



        recyclerView.addOnItemTouchListener(new RecyclerTouchListener(getActivity(), recyclerView, new RecyclerTouchListener.ClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view, int position) {
                Artists artist = artistList.get(position);
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), artist.getArtistName() + " is selected!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

            @Override
            public void onLongClick(View view, int position) {

                Artists artist = artistList.get(position);

                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), artist.getArtistName() + " is long pressed selected!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
        }));


    }


    public void prepareArtistData(){
        for(int i=0;i<names.length;i++){

            Artists artist = new Artists(names[i], type[i], images[i]);
            artistList.add(artist);

        }

        mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }


}
```

HorizontalListViewFragment.java

```
package com.example.majedhussain.loginsample;

/**
 * Created by anonymous on 11/4/16.
 */

import android.content.ContentResolver;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class HorizontalListViewFragment extends Fragment {

    ArrayList<Artists> listitems = new ArrayList<>();
    RecyclerView MyRecyclerView;
    String ArtistsS[] = {"Hrithik","Ranbir","AkshayKumar","Amir Khan","Shahidi Kapoor"};
    int  Images[] = {R.drawable.index1,R.drawable.index2,R.drawable.index3,R.drawable.index4,R.drawable.index5};
    @Override
    public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        listitems.clear();
        for(int i =0;i<ArtistsS.length;i++){
            Artists item = new Artists();
            item.setArtistName(ArtistsS[i]);
            item.setImageResourceId(Images[i]);
            item.setIsfav(0);
            item.setIsturned(0);
            listitems.add(item);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_horizontal_list_view, container, false);
        MyRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.cardView);
        MyRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        LinearLayoutManager MyLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
        MyLayoutManager.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL);
        if (listitems.size() > 0 & MyRecyclerView != null) {
            MyRecyclerView.setAdapter(new MyAdapter(listitems));
        }
        MyRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(MyLayoutManager);

        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

    }

    public class MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyViewHolder> {
        private ArrayList<Artists> list;

        public MyAdapter(ArrayList<Artists> Data) {
            list = Data;
        }

        @Override
        public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
            // create a new view
            View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                    .inflate(R.layout.recycle_items, parent, false);
            MyViewHolder holder = new MyViewHolder(view);
            return holder;
        }

        @Override
        public void onBindViewHolder(final MyViewHolder holder, int position) {

            holder.titleTextView.setText(list.get(position).getArtistName());
            holder.coverImageView.setImageResource(list.get(position).getImageResourceId());
            holder.coverImageView.setTag(list.get(position).getImageResourceId());
            holder.likeImageView.setTag(R.drawable.ic_like);

        }

        @Override
        public int getItemCount() {
            return list.size();
        }
    }

    public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        public TextView titleTextView;
        public ImageView coverImageView;
        public ImageView likeImageView;
        public ImageView shareImageView;

        public MyViewHolder(View v) {
            super(v);
            titleTextView = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.titleTextView);
            coverImageView = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.coverImageView);
            likeImageView = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.likeImageView);
            shareImageView = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.shareImageView);
            likeImageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {


                    int id = (int)likeImageView.getTag();
                    if( id == R.drawable.ic_like){

                        likeImageView.setTag(R.drawable.ic_liked);
                        likeImageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_liked);

                        Toast.makeText(getActivity(),titleTextView.getText()+" added to favourites", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    }else{

                        likeImageView.setTag(R.drawable.ic_like);
                        likeImageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_like);
                        Toast.makeText(getActivity(),titleTextView.getText()+" removed from favourites", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


                    }

                }
            });



            shareImageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                    Uri imageUri = Uri.parse(ContentResolver.SCHEME_ANDROID_RESOURCE +
                            "://" + getResources().getResourcePackageName(coverImageView.getId())
                            + '/' + "drawable" + '/' + getResources().getResourceEntryName((int)coverImageView.getTag()));


                    Intent shareIntent = new Intent();
                    shareIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                    shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM,imageUri);
                    shareIntent.setType("image/jpeg");
                    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent, getResources().getText(R.string.send_to)));



                }
            });



        }
    }
}
```

Artists.java

```
package com.example.majedhussain.loginsample;

/**
 * Created by MAJED HUSSAIN on 14-06-2017.
 */

public class Artists {
    String artistName;
    String desc;
    int imageResourceId;
    int isfav;
    int isturned;


    public Artists(String artistName, String desc, int imageResourceId) {
        this.artistName = artistName;
        this.desc = desc;
        this.imageResourceId = imageResourceId;
    }

    public Artists() {
    }

    public void setDesc(String desc){
        this.desc = desc;
    }

    public String getDesc() {
        return desc;
    }

    public int getIsturned() {
        return isturned;
    }

    public void setIsturned(int isturned) {
        this.isturned = isturned;
    }

    public int getIsfav() {
        return isfav;
    }

    public void setIsfav(int isfav) {
        this.isfav = isfav;
    }

    public String getArtistName() {
        return artistName;
    }

    public void setArtistName(String artistName) {
        this.artistName = artistName;
    }

    public int getImageResourceId() {
        return imageResourceId;
    }

    public void setImageResourceId(int imageResourceId) {
        this.imageResourceId = imageResourceId;
    }

}
```

MainActivity.java

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.design.widget.TabLayout;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.view.View;
import android.support.design.widget.NavigationView;
import android.support.v4.view.GravityCompat;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
        implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener,TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener {
    private TabLayout tabLayout;
    private ViewPager viewPager;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .setAction("Action", null).show();
            }
        });

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
        drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();

        NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);


        tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabLayout);

        //Adding the tabs using addTab() method
        tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Home"));
        tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Favourites"));
        tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Trending"));
        tabLayout.setTabGravity(TabLayout.GRAVITY_FILL);

        //Initializing viewPager
        viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);

        //Creating our pager adapter
        Pager adapter = new Pager(getSupportFragmentManager(), tabLayout.getTabCount());

        //Adding adapter to pager
        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);


        viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new TabLayout.TabLayoutOnPageChangeListener(tabLayout));


        //Adding onTabSelectedListener to swipe views
        tabLayout.setOnTabSelectedListener(this);




    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
            drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        if (id == R.id.nav_camera) {
            // Handle the camera action
        } else if (id == R.id.nav_gallery) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_slideshow) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_manage) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_share) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_send) {

        }

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
        viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

    }
}
```

output images are:
[This is the first output in which horizontal list is visible](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eh8XL.png)

[This is the second output after I visited first tab and came back. now horizontal list is disappeared](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bBTLo.png)

Comment: are you using ViewPager adapter to show your tabs?

Comment: Yes I am using ViewPager adapter, should I add MainActivity code where tabs are added?

Comment: can you post your ViewPager adapter code?

Comment: I have added MainActivity.java code in which ViewPager adapter codes are written, please check

Comment: Is there anything to do with getSupportFragmentManager() and getFragmentManager()? because I used getSupportFragmentManager() in MainActivity and getFragmentManager() in Tab3.java

Comment: I am not seeing any Pager adapter code in above code in MainActivity.class.

Comment: Its in the bottom of onCreate() method

Comment: you have to write separate class for your Pager ViewAdapter to define your tab fragments.

Comment: I got the solution. I removed an if condition which checks whether the fragment is null or not in Tab3.java. Thank you for your response

Comment: ok good ........

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your fragment is not null:

```
Fragment fragment = fm.findFragmentById(R.id.fragmentContainer);

    if (fragment == null) {
        fragment = new HorizontalListViewFragment();
        ;
        fm.beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.fragmentContainer, fragment)
                .commit();
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, any solution for this? should I make it as != instead of ==?

Comment: I think you dont need to check if fragment is null or not because you need to create and add a fragment to your view

Comment: oh it worked! that problem is solved when I deleted that if condition, but now it shows a warning here-  Fragment fragment = fm.findFragmentById(R.id.fragmentContainer);